# display an alert when the content of a <p> element reaches a certain string

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is a webpage that counts your clicks on the button my problem is i want it to display an alert when the number reaches 100 and i tried but i cant i saw a lot of posts/tutorials i cant figure it out. i want to make an if statement that reads the p element
and display an alert when the p element  content is "clicks: 100" note: im a beginner and this is a couple of days work so please explain easily and if there was any other mistakes notify me and thanks

````
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>clicks counter</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  
.btn{
height: 550px;
width: 550px;
top: 20%;
border-radius: 20px;
position: absolute;
right: 35%;
background-color: gray;
font-size: 100px;
}
.clicks{
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 50px;
color: white;
left: 37%;
position: absolute
}


</style>


<body style="background-color: #181818;">

<button id="btn" class="btn">click me!</button>


<p id="Count" class="clicks">clicks:0</p>

<script>

var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var counter = 1;
var theCount = document.getElementById('Count');

btn.addEventListener("click", addcps);

function addcps() {

  theCount.innerHTML = "clicks: " + counter +"" ;
  counter++
}
 
if (document.getElementById('Count').innerHTML == "clicks: 100") {

alert("reached 100");


}
</script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: You shouldn't read the contents of the `<p>` element to determine when to show the alert, you should base that on the value of the variable that is counting the clicks. The `<p>` element merely displays the value of the variable — it is not what is doing the counting.

Comment: You can include the `if statement` with the alert inside the function so when it reaches a 100 your alert will show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should count the total number of click based on the `counter` not on the `innerHTML`

> For demo purpose I've limit it to count 5

If you put if statement for checking then it will work only for the first time when JS runs but you have to check everytime when the user clicks button, So put it into `addcps`.

Count should be start with `var counter = 0;` if you are counting the clicks

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var counter = 0;
var theCount = document.getElementById('Count');

btn.addEventListener("click", addcps);

function addcps() {
  counter++
  theCount.textContent = "clicks: " + counter + "";
  if (counter === 5) {
    alert("reached 100");
  }
}
```

```css
.btn {
  height: 550px;
  width: 550px;
  top: 20%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 35%;
  background-color: gray;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.clicks {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  /* color: white; */
  left: 37%;
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" class="btn">click me!</button>


<p id="Count" class="clicks">clicks: 0</p>
```